# How to use pandas to agg data with different condition for different columns?

Tags: python, pandas

[Agg by sales](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7XNB.png)

Original Data:

| Sales | Product | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| James | apple | 10 |
| Johnson | apple | 1 |
| Jessie | banana | 2 |
| Judy | melon | 5 |
| James | melon | 5 |
| Jessie | apple | 8 |

To:

| Sales | Apple | Melon | Banana | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| James | 10 | 5 | 0 | 15 |
| Judy | 0 | 5 | 0 | 5 |
| Jessie | 8 | 0 | 2 | 10 |
| Johnson | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

I'd like to calcuate the amount for each product and group by each sales with pandas, so how to do this by pandas?

Comment: I just used pivot_table to make this work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With df as your dataframe name Try:

```
temp_df = df.pivot_table(index='Sales', columns='Product', aggfunc=sum)
cols = [ind[1] for ind in np.array(temp_df.columns)]
data = np.array(temp_df)
final_df = pd.DataFrame({'Sales':temp_df.index})
for i, col in enumerate(cols):
    final_df = pd.concat((final_df, pd.DataFrame({col:data[:, i]})), axis=1)
final_df = final_df.fillna(0)
final_df['total'] = final_df.iloc[:, 1:].sum(axis=1)
```